# Currency code to a symbol - PHP JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, currency

I want to create a system that will return the official currency symbol by receiving the currency code (3 letters), which means that once the function receives USD it will return the $ sign and so to all the denominator in the world.

The result I get with the function I published is wrong (I would like to get $ for USD and not د.إ.‏ for AED). I have no idea why? TIA

> ```
> Array ( 
>     [symbol] => AED [symbol_native] => د.إ.‏ 
>     [decimal_digits] => 2 
>     [rounding] => 0 [code] => AED   
> )
> ```

```
   function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
    }

    function searchJson( $obj, $value ) {
        foreach( $obj as $key => $item ) {
            if( !is_nan( intval( $key ) ) && is_array( $item ) ){
                if( in_array( $value, $item ) ) return $item;
            } else {
                foreach( $item as $child ) {
                    if(isset($child) && $child == $value) {
                        return $child;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    function get_currency_symbol($cur)
    {
    $json = file_get_contents_curl('http://www.localeplanet.com/api/auto/currencymap.json');    
    $data = json_decode( $json, true);
    $results = searchJson( $data , $cur );
    return $results;
    }

    print_r(get_currency_symbol('USD'));
```

Comment: 1. Do you really need to fetch that JSON file every single time? I don't think currency symbols are changing all that often, a local copy of that file or a simple lookup array would perfectly suffice. 2. Show us a sample of the data you're working with.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do in your `searchJson()`-function. All that function need to contain is: `return !empty($obj[$value]) ? $obj[$value]['symbol_native'] : null;` and it will return the correct symbol, if it exists.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Perfect Thank you alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to match your string with json decoded key.

```
function searchJson( $obj, $value ) {      
        foreach( $obj as $key => $item ) {
          if(strtolower($key) == strtolower($value))
            return $item;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/GT5XP)

OR simply check index directly

```
function searchJson( $obj, $value ) { 
        $data = isset($obj[$value])?$obj[$value]:null;        
        return $data;
    }
```